# Необходима ли запятая перед и?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Если он попытается украсть кольцо и его застукают, вам несдобровать".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Если он попытается украсть кольцо и (если) его застукают, вам несдобровать.**

Запятая не нужна, союз И соединяет однородные придаточные. Второе придаточное односоставное, нет подлежащего.